# Value of $\lambda$ such that two limits are equal

Tags: calculus, limits

Referring to the figure below, find the value of $\lambda$ such that two limits are equal: 
$$2\left[{\lim_{x \to 0} f(x^3-x^2)}\right]=\lambda\left[{\lim_{x \to 0} f(2x^4-x^5)}\right]$$

[image]

Comment: @samjoe "Use L'hospital" Huh? Sorry but what exactly do you have in mind? Or is this yet another instance of *L'H the mind killer*?

Comment: @samjoe And this is wildly offtopic, right?

Comment: @samjoe No, **your comment** is offtopic (worse, it sends the OP in a direction that does not work, simply because you were too lazy to check that the first idea that crossed your mind was pertinent before posting it). Quite unrelatedly, yes the question lacks context but this is another beef.

Comment: @Did Oops sorry again, I removed my misguiding comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $x$ is close to $0$, the leading behavior is given by the lowest power. That is $x^2$ for the term on the left, and $x^4$ for the term on the right. In this case $-x^2+x^3$ is always negative in a small neighborhood of $0$, so the limit on the left is $3$. Similarly, $2x^4-x^5$ is greater than $0$, so the limit is $2$. Therefore $$2\cdot3=\lambda\cdot2$$